# Unable to CreateProject in PhoneGap

Tags: phonegap-desktop-app

I am new in PhoneGap.

After installing PhoneGap desktop application for Windows 7, I tried to create a simple hello world application.  After specifying project name, path, when I click on Create Project button, initially, it gives error as "connect ETIMEOUT 192.30.252.128:443" - This is due to the reason that I am in corporate network.

Further, if I try to disconnect from any network then I am getting "getaddrinfo enoent github.com:443" - This is due to the reason that I am not connected to any network.

Is there any way to use PhoneGap in corporate network?

I tried changing my port form 3000 to 2000 or something else, but that did not work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get PhoneGap Desktop to work on a corporate network is to get your IT department to either allow exceptions in the network's security policy for the PhoneGap Desktop.

At my office, we were able to get a wireless hotspot set up and configured for dev & testing with the PhoneGap Desktop App.